# How to slice n+ entries in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the top N rows of dataframe sorted by the column price in descending order.
But if I have other rows in the dataframe that has a price equal to the last row (N-th row), I want to show them as well.
How to proceed?

Suppose I have these 3 rows:
id price

```
A  30
B  35 
C  30
D  15
```

Suppose N = 2:

```
car_dataframe.sort_values(by=['price'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
return car_dataframe[:2]
```

This would return:

```
B 35
A 30
```

But because C has the same price of the last N-th row(A), I want to return C as well.
So it should return:

```
B 35
A 30
C 30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with `keep="all"`:

```
df.nlargest(n=2, columns="price", keep="all")
```

```
  id  price
1  B     35
0  A     30
2  C     30
```